# ASP .NET MVC KendoUI, how to pass observable viewModel property to MVC Action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have a view template which is able to display data from a kendo.observable viewmodel.
However, as part of the view template, I want to render a partial view which accepts a parameter. How can I pass the parameter to the action?

In the below example, the

```
<div data-bind="text: data.name"></div>
```

works. Now, how do I pass the data.name to the

```
@Html.Action("_Discounts", "GroupBuys", new { name = data.name })
```

//View Template which is databound to viewmodel

```
<script id="details-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
<div class="details">
    <div class="info-container">
        <div data-bind="text: data.name"></div>
        <div data-bind="text: data.description"></div>
        ${data.name} //This by itself works
        @Html.Action("_Discounts", "GroupBuys", new { name = ${data.name} }) //Doesn't work
    </div>
</div>
</script>
```

//CONTROLLER ACTION ACCEPTING PARAMETER "name"

```
public ActionResult _FindName(string name)
{
  ...
}
```

I have tried:

```
@Html.Action("_Discounts", "GroupBuys", new { name = @:data.name }) 
@Html.Action("_Discounts", "GroupBuys", new { name = @:"${data.name}" }) 
@Html.Action("_Discounts", "GroupBuys", new { name = ${data.name} })
```

None seems to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try `@Html.Action("_Discounts", "GroupBuys", new { name = "${data.name}" })`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Anto. Unfortunately, it did not work. By the time it makes to the controller, it comes in as ${data.name} instead of actually giving me the name itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Html.Action("_Discounts", "GroupBuys", new { name = ${data.name} })
```

Remember this is server side code. It will be rendered on the page before kendo JavaScript starts running in the browser so your kendo.observable viewmodel does not exist at this point.

This is the case even if your using Kendo MVC bindings as all they do is render JavaScript on the page.

My suggestion is to do an Ajax call for your partial and in the success of the ajax rework your template with the returned HTML.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'YourURL',
    data: { name: "name" },
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function (html) {
        $("#selectDivForReturnedHtmlInKendoTemplate").replace(html);
        var template = kendo.template($('#details-template'));
        renderTemplate(template);
    },
    error: function (e) {
        ajaxError(e);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. Your answer led me in the right direction, and I got the result I wanted.

Comment: Jonathan , i have array of Complex object. I am using ASP.NET MVC and kendo mvvm . Other than defining model  using kendo.data.Model.define
     is there any other way?

Comment: @DashangG.Makwana: So there is nothing wrong with using a more complex object. You just need to ensure that the JSON in your ajax request is serialized the right way (and de-serialized in your C# controller). I'll add that if the size of your data is too much though you will want to switch the default HTTP verb of the ajax request from a 'GET' to 'POST'. A HTTPGET can only support 256 characters I think.

Comment: @Jonathan i want to provide user ability to add and delete object from array of complex objects. i want to add/remove item  from array of complex object how can i do that without defining that whole object using kendo.data.model.define  ?it is too much thing for large complex objects .. it was not about sending complex object

Comment: @JonathanBuchanan Please reply above query

Comment: So the Model you supply to your kendo control only defines a schema on how to pull data from each object in your array of data. You can always have extra un-used data points in your data objects. You can also add and remove data object from this array (manually or with kendo's built in read transport) but it may require a refresh of the control to update the UI. Finally, if you mean that you are trying to update the Schema Model I would instead suggest destroying and rebuilding the control instead.

Comment: @JonathanBuchanan I have found something that works without defining model in kendo.data.Model.define but only works when with code : ' AirRequestViewModel.AirItem.AirVMList.SegmentInfo.push(AirRequestViewModel.AirItem.AirVMList.SegmentSkeleton)  '
not with code : ' this.AirVMList.SegmentInfo.push(this.AirVMList.SegmentSkeleton) ' why so ? why with 'this' keyword its not wirking ?

Comment: I can't tell from just that. I'd suggest that you frame your own question with all the details so that you can get the help you need.